# Pick random array element from string, but same string always returns same element. Pseudo-random

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, ecmascript-6

I have an array of possible colors in Javascript:

```
possibleColors = [
        "#10ace3",
        "#f26529",
        "#c62328",
        "#e53434",
        "#ffba49",
        "#99c24d",
        "#7e1d1d"
      ]
```

Given a string (the person's name), I'd like to always pick the same color, randomly.

As an example:

```
"Sergio" would always return the first color.
"Daniel" would always return the fourth color.
etc.
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? Please don't take my example literally I just mean the same string should return the same color.

Comment: Could you provide more information about what you are trying to achieve? My best answer would be to store these in `localStorage`, but without more information I am lost.

Comment: This sentence definitely confuses me: "I'd like to always pick the same color, randomly."

Comment: Find an implementation of crc32 and calculate the hash of input string, then modulo the result with the length of array.

Comment: does the `possibleColors` order or count change on every run?

Comment: They could add a color or remove a color later on, and if so, I would expect the color for "Sergio" to change - that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the name is dynamically given, you will have to assign it a color on the first entry then make sure every subsequent entry returns the same color.

If you know the name in advance, then you just create a map to return the same color.

In any case, some sort mapping has to be created.

For example:

```
const nameColorMap = new Map()
const possibleColors = [ "#10ace3", "#f26529", "#c62328", "#e53434", "#ffba49", "#99c24d", "#7e1d1d"]

function getColorForName(name) {
  if (!nameColorMap.has(name)) {
    const color = possibleColors[Math.round(Math.random() * possibleColors.length)]
    nameColorMap.set(
      name,
      color,
    )
  }

  return nameColorMap.get(name)
}
```

https://repl.it/@baruchvlz/GrubbyAgonizingOffice

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take advantage of some sort of storage, such as [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or a backend database such as [MySQL](http://mysql.com)

Since SO doesn't support localStorage snippets, here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o65xa4gq/) of the below code:

```
const possibleColors = [
        "#10ace3",
        "#f26529",
        "#c62328",
        "#e53434",
        "#ffba49",
        "#99c24d",
        "#7e1d1d"
      ]

function getColor(str) {
  // Attempt the get the item from local storage (returns null otherwise)
  let color = localStorage.getItem(str)
  if(!color) {
    // Nothing was in local storage, select a random color
    color = possibleColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleColors.length)]
    // Save the color to local storage for use next time
    localStorage.setItem(str, color)
  }
  // Return the color that was or now is in local storage
  return color
}

console.log('jim', getColor('jim'))
console.log('bob', getColor('bob'))

console.log('jim', getColor('jim'))
console.log('brass monkey', getColor('brass monkey'))
console.log('jim', getColor('jim'))

console.log('brass monkey', getColor('brass monkey'))
console.log('brass monkey', getColor('brass monkey'))
```

Rerunning the script multiple times will give the same results with the same string. Reloading the page will do the same thing since the value(s) are stored in storage.

```
// Example possible output:
//
// jim           #7e1d1d
// bob           #c62328
// jim           #7e1d1d
// brass monkey  #e53434
// jim           #7e1d1d
// brass monkey  #e53434
// brass monkey  #e53434
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store the person name and their color, if he is a new person, let bring him a random color, in opposite return his color.

```
const possibleColors = [
  "#10ace3",
  "#f26529",
  "#c62328",
  "#e53434",
  "#ffba49",
  "#99c24d",
  "#7e1d1d"
];

let  getColor = (function() {
  let cache = {};
  let f = function(name) {
    if (!cache[name]) {
      cache[name] = possibleColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleColors.length)];
    }

    return cache[name];
  }
  return f;
})();

console.log(getColor('Sergio'));
console.log(getColor('Sergio'));
console.log(getColor('Sergio'));

console.log(getColor('Daniel'));
console.log(getColor('Daniel'));
console.log(getColor('Daniel'));
```